# Debugging search_api (no results in production)

Tags: 8, search

I'm using search api, search api autocomplete, and search api pages.

I want a search engine for my taxonomy terms.

I configured the modules in the same way locally, and in production, locally, everything works, in production, the terms are indexed, the search suggestions work, but the search does not return any results.

I have been searching for several hours, I emptied the cache X times, reindexed the terms X times etc. but I still do not get any results.

I sometimes had an error in my journal (not always):

> Search keys are given but no fulltext fields are defined.

However, I have added a fulltext field in my index corresponding to Taxnomy> name.

I am a little hopeless.

Does anyone have any idea where the problem may come from?

Comment: Just to check, do you have permission on production to view the content that would show up as results? Viewing as admin?

Comment: I am logged in as an administrator. But I checked, and yes, I have the permissions

Comment: Are you using Drupal's config sync, or Features module to handle config between environments? I would say make a backup of your local DB and pull down production, do you have the same issue? Trying to narrow it down...